# VBA IE click button that requires argument?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, radio-button

*I'm using Excel and programming in VBA.*

I've located a button that I want to click. However, it seems this button requires an argument.

Using the Console in Chrome, I typed this:

```
document.getElementById("button1").click
```

That line resolved `function click() { [native code] }`
so instead I tried this:

```
document.getElementById("button1").click ('100', '2016-03-02')
```

And it worked. So, how do I run the same thing from VBA?

I have tried the following:

```
Sub ClickTheButton()
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "(webpage here)"

    Do Until Not .Busy And .ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set Doc = .Document

    Doc.GetElementByID("button1").Click ' nothing happens when running this
    Doc.GetElementByID("button1").Click "('100', '2016-03-02')" ' not working (can't even attempt to run this)
    Doc.GetElementByID("button1").Click ("'100', '2016-03-02'") ' not working (can't even attempt to run this)

End With
End Sub
```

I can't run the procedure, because of the code after `.Click` returning `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `Doc.getElementById("button1").click "100", "2016-03-02"`   What language were you using when it worked ?  Also would be helpful to post a URL or the relevant HTML.

Comment: I can't provide the real URL since it requires me to login to a site (it's for clicking a button that books a session. However, I just used the console in Chrome. Also, your suggestion doesn't work in VBA, it still thinks nothing should be placed after the `.Click` (that error about invalid property assignments).

Answer (score 1):

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247391/click-button-or-execute-javascript-function-with-vba).

The click button ran a function. Instead of clicking the button I could instead just run the function like this:

```
Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy    
Set CurrentWindow = IE.Document.parentWindow
Call CurrentWindow.execScript("xajax_DoCalReservation('100', '2016-03-02')")
```