# VBA - How can I click the link ( No name/Id/Class )

Tags: html, vba, browser

I am trying to click a download and a graph link on a webpage and I can not seem to get it to work.

Everything I've worked with so far seems to have an ID/Name/Class that work well with getElementById/Name call, but with this link I cant seem to find anything that will reference to it and click. Please, help me!

CODE:

```
<.a href="#" onclick="spr_command('plot_graph'); return false;">Graph</a>
<.a href="#" onclick="spr_command('download'); return false;">Download</a>
```

Comment: you need to execute the JS. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247391/click-button-or-execute-javascript-function-with-vba

Comment: Thanks very much! It works well. You made my day.

Comment: @cyboashu How should I write the script to execute this following method                                                                                                                     `code <a onclick="var dl_var = find_control('download'); dl_var.value = '1'; submitFormByPost(dl_var.form); dl_var.value = ''; return false;" href="#">`

Comment: I tried `code Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy 
Set CurrentWindow = ie.Document.parentWindow
Call CurrentWindow.execScript("var dl_var = find_control('download')") `  but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you comment cyboashu!

It works pretty well!

The solution is:

```
Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy 
Set CurrentWindow = ie.Document.parentWindow
Call CurrentWindow.execScript("spr_command('plot_graph')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `getElementsByTagName("a")`? and the `FireEvent('OnClick')`

Comment: You mean:                                                                                                             Set Element = .document.getElementsTagName("spr_command('plot_graph')")(0)
    Element.FireEvent ("onclick")

Comment: no, document.getElementsByTagName("a"), then you'll need to look through them for their innerText/innerHTML to be "download"  spr_command is the function called on click

Comment: Thanks for you colaboration! I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

a simple javascript will do.

```js
window.spr_command = function(action){
   alert(action);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="spr_command('plot_graph'); return false;">Graph <br />

<a href="#" onclick="spr_command('download'); return false;">Download
```

Comment: How should I write it in VBA?