# Execute a click button with VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

How can I execute the following click button using VBA:

```
<a href='javascript:
        openLoadProgress(document.forms.AddFund);
        document.forms.AddFund.PASS_OFF.value = "/issuer/search_for_issuer.jsp?fromPage=/add_promote_uae.jsp&amp;ChangeIndex=-1&amp;fromAddIssuerPage=null&amp;EntityType=M";
        document.forms.AddFund.submit()'

    onclick="document.AddFund.fromPage.value='/add_promote_uae.jsp';">
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
Set CurrentWindow = IE.document.parentWindow 

Call CurrentWindow.execScript("openLoadProgress('search_for_issuer.jsp?')")
```

Comment: I think there must be at least 100 questions asking exactly this on this site. Did you *try* to search?

Comment: Yes. That approach I'm trying was found here as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247391/click-button-or-execute-javascript-function-with-vba

Comment: You're going to have to better explain what the problem is. "It's not working" isn't a *programmer's* problem statement, it's how a *user* complains.

Comment: is this for  Luxembourg Stock Exchange  https://www.bourse.lu ?  maybe they changed their website to prevent web scraping.

Comment: No is not Luxembourg Stock Exchange. I will try some other stuff that I found and see how it goes. I will fix the post or delete it as needed.